# Why Laravel Pagination stuck at page 1?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

I have a very simple Laravel application. Basically I'm using Eloquent to pull out data from the DB and paginate them.

However it's not working properly. Every time I'm using the paginate command I'm getting the first page's result only.

Here's my code:

```
$forum = new Forum;
$posts = $forum->paginate(5);
return $posts;
```

What I'm getting back as JSON is:

```
total: 33,
per_page: 5,
current_page: 1,
last_page: 7,
next_page_url: "http://xxxxxxx.com/load?page=2",
prev_page_url: null,
from: 1,
to: 5,
```

... and the first 5 results.

When I click to the next page URL it's loading the exact same first page results and I have the exact same response:

```
total: 33,
per_page: 5,
current_page: 1,
last_page: 7,
next_page_url: "http://xxxxxxx.com/load?page=2",
prev_page_url: null,
from: 1,
to: 5,
```

...with the same 5 first posts.

I haven't changed any settings in Laravel and I'm using Laravel 5.2.

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: Is your page redirecting somehow and losing some of the parameters from your URL?

Comment: Are you loading the results with AJAX (I ask because you mentioned JSON)?

Comment: @user3158900 Nope. When I'm visiting http://xxxxxxx.com/load?page=2 my url bar shows the same page.

Comment: @jfadich Yes, I was. However it was not working (got the same error) that's why I've switched to simple GET and loaded the URL in the browser to see if Ajax is the issue. But it wasn't.

Comment: If you do a `dd(\Request::get('page'))` right before paginating does it show the correct page number?

Comment: @jfadich Hmm, good catch! I'm getting `null` there! How's that possible. Maybe it's something with my Nginx config?

Comment: Checked it on another page and I'm getting the `page` variable on other page. Expect this one!

Comment: @jfadich Actually query strings are only working on the Index page. Not on the other controllers.

Comment: Not familiar with nginx but I found this...  http://serverfault.com/questions/231578/nginx-php-fpm-where-are-my-get-params

Comment: I agree with @user3158900. It seems like somewhere your query is getting lost. Since it only works on the index page your nginx config may be the culprit. Make sure the config looks something like `location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}`

Comment: @jfadich, yes this was the exact issue, Thanks